# Regex to replace first occurrence of x with first occurrence of y

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a string:

```
123,234,345,456,567
abc,bcd,cde,def.
```

I want to replace first occurrence of `'\d{3},'` with first occurrence of `'\w{3},'` and second occurrence of `'\d{3},'` with second occurrence of `'\w{3},'` and so on...

Note: I'm actually using a simple find replace in Notepad++.

Comment: Which language you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little bit difficult given just one sample, but given the following text content:

```
123,234,345,456,567
abc,bcd,cde,def.
```

Using the following:

- Find what: `(\d{3},)(\d{3})(.+?)(([a-zA-Z]{3},)([a-zA-Z]{3}).+)`
- Replace with: `\5\6\3\4`
- Search Mode: Regular expression (ensuring that `.` matches newline is **selected**).

Will yield the following:

```
abc,bcd,345,456,567
abc,bcd,cde,def.
```

An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/pA6yN7/1).